# Function to prevent special characters in nickname

Tags: php, char, special-characters

I've a website where users can register.  I would like to prevent all special characters, accents, etc in  the nickname (used to login).

I use PHP.  How can I do that ?

Edit: Another question, can you give me a regular expression (in PHP) who allow ONLY the 26 letters : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz and no more ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$username = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $username);
```

If you really just mean lowercase a-z, remove the i flag.

In response to comment, the regexp becomes [^a-z0-9]

Comment: Only the 26 letters `a`–`z` and no more.

Comment: Ok and if I want also 123456789 ?

Comment: Extra ! So with this line: $username = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $username); my $username will can only contain abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz (lowercase and uppercase) AND 123456789 ? Ok, right ?

Comment: @Jen Gerfeld: a-z0-9 OR *nothing*. If the string had no valid characters, it will now be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's **[normalizer](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php)** functions for that.